# Convert number of week and year to date

Tags: flutter, date, dart

how can I convert week number and year to date? example?

4720 it's, week 47 of date 2020.

In php i have something like this: echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2020W47"));

Thanks!

Comment: by "date" you mean `DatatTime` class?

Comment: DateTime class or string format

Comment: sorry "47" not "74"

Comment: The [isoweek package](https://pub.dev/packages/isoweek) looks like it could help you.

Comment: @pskink If [ISO week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) is desired, I don't think it's quite as simple as that.

Comment: @LucaBecchetti how would first week of 2020 look like?